# DOMException: The source image could not be decoded (after update the openlayers 8)

Tags: javascript, angular, openlayers

after updating the openlayers v8.1.0
wms images not displaying anymore on map and throwing this error
DOMException: The source image could not be decoded

```
const wmsLayer = new ImageLayer({
      source: this.addColorFunction(current.inst, src),
      visible: false
    });

src.on('imageloadstart', loader.startLoad.bind(loader));
    src.on('imageloadend', loader.endLoad.bind(loader));
    src.on(
      'imageloaderror',
      function(e) {
        that.logger.error(
          'Fehler beim Laden eines WMS-Bildes von "' + current.cfg.name + '"', {error: e}
        );
        loader.endLoad();
      }.bind(this)
    );
```

error logger WMS-Bildes

i did try to find if the is some changes in openlayers v8, related to wms images but nothing at all.
Here is the openlayers migration https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/changelog/upgrade-notes.md

i have the images in request not only throwing the error but not showing the images.

Comment: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/15109